# ¿Cómo evitar StaleElementReferenceException? Selenium + Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Estoy trabajando con Selenium en una web dínamica. La web tiene un select y una tabla (Solo el header). Cuando abro la web por **primera vez** selecciono una opción en el select y se generan las filas de la tabla, los datos de las celdas los obtengo así:

```
   cells = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='tBuscar']/tbody/tr/td")))
```

En una de las columnas de esa tabla hay links, y cuando los clickeo se abre una ChildWindow en el navegador y me enseña una "SubPage" (por llamarlo de alguna forma).

Seguidamente voy a otra pestaña del navegador y trabajo con otra web.
(Hasta aquí todo perfecto)

Ahora intento repetir la operación por **segunda vez**: Regreso otra vez a la página inicial con mi select y mi tabla, vuelvo a seleccionar una opción del select e intento obtener los nuevos datos de la tabla, pero esta vez obtengo una excepción.

Esto es lo que produce la excepción:

```
cells[x].get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Y este es el mensaje que obtengo:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: 
Message: The element reference of  <td class="trs-cod"> 
is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is n
ot in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

***document has been refreshed***

Creo que importante decir que las filas de la tabla no son constantes, es decir, se destruyen o se crean dependiendo de la opción seleccionada en el select. (Puede tener 10 filas como puede tener 50 por poner un ejemplo).

No estoy totalmente seguro de cual de todas las acciones que hago es la causante de que la página se refresque, lo mas probable es que sea porque la tabla es dínamica, aunque es un poco extraño porque la primera vez que se abre la página, la tabla no contiene filas hasta que se selecciona una opción en el select.

He estado viendo que hay gente que lo soluciona de esta forma pero a mi no me funciona:

```
 step=0
 stop=3

 while step<stop:
  try:         

   cells = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='tBuscar']/tbody/tr/td")))  
   cells[x].get_attribute('innerHTML')   
   step=3
  except StaleElementReferenceException:
    time.sleep(1)
    step+=1
    if step==stop:
     print("StaleElementReferenceException: No se pudo obtener los elementos de la tabla")
     sys.exit(-1)
```

### ¿Alguna otra ídea para solucionarlo?

### -------------------------------ACTUALIZACION---------------------------------

A continuación muestro las partes mi código que creo que son mas relevantes para que se vea bien como lo estoy haciendo, pues según los comentarios puede que no esté muy claro.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":   

 log = read_log()
 inicio = int(log[0])+1


 driver = init() 
 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY, poll_frequency=0.25)

 #login en la página 1
 act_open_main_page(driver)
 act_login(driver) 
 act_open_db(driver)

 #abrir nueva pestaña
 driver.execute_script("window.open()")
 driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

 #login en la página 2
 car_open_login_page(driver)
 car_login(driver) 


 #volver a la primera pestaña (página 1)
 driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])


 marcas_select = act_conseguir_marcas(driver, wait)
 n_marcas = len(marcas_select.options)

 #Aquí hago un loop para ir marca por marca
 for i in range(inicio-1, n_marcas):

  index = i+1

  #volver a la primera pestaña (página 1)
  driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

  #Este es el select para seleccionar las marcas
  marcas_select.select_by_index(index)

  #Y cuando se hace click en este boton se genera la tabla con los productos
  act_boton_buscar_click(driver, wait)
  procucto = Producto()

  #Y AQUÍ ES DONDE FALLA (EN LA SEGUNDA  ITERACIÓN)
  procucto = act_seleccionar_productos(driver, wait)


  if procucto != None: #La marca tiene productos

   #Ir a la segunda pestaña (página 2)
   driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

   #Y aquí otro loop para ir producto por producto
   for i in range( len(procucto.nombre)  ):
    #Aquí hago algunas operaciones en la segunda página
```

***Y esta es la función que me esta fallado en la segunda iteración***

```
def act_seleccionar_productos(driver, wait):

 step=0
 stop=3 

 while step<stop:
  try:     
   descripcion_script = get_descripcion_links(driver, wait)
   if len(descripcion_script)==0:
    return None         


   rows = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='tBuscar']/tbody/tr")))      

   cells = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='tBuscar']/tbody/tr/td")))        

   product_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tBuscar']/tbody/tr/td/span")

   row_count = len(rows)
   column_count = 14 

   print ("filas=%s columnas=%s  cells=%s" % (row_count, column_count, len(cells)-1 ) )


   matriz = crear_matriz(cells, row_count, column_count)

   procucto = Producto()

   for i in range(row_count):
    referencia = matriz[i][0].get_attribute('innerHTML')
    nombre = product_name[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')
    marca = matriz[i][2].get_attribute('innerHTML')
    pvf = matriz[i][7].get_attribute('innerHTML')
    pvp = matriz[i][8].get_attribute('innerHTML')

    descripcion = act_manejar_descripcion(driver, wait, i, descripcion_script)

    procucto.referencia.append(referencia)
    procucto.nombre.append(nombre)
    procucto.marca.append(marca)
    procucto.pvf.append(pvf)
    procucto.pvp.append(pvp)
    procucto.descripcion.append(descripcion)    

   step=3
   return procucto
  except StaleElementReferenceException:
   time.sleep(1)
   step+=1
   if step==stop:
    print("StaleElementReferenceException: No se pudo obtener los elementos de la tabla")
    sys.exit(-1)
```

Comment: Hola Ivan, lo que describes como pasos que hace tu codigo no me cuadra con lo que muestras despues. Aun asi, despues de los steps hasta que te falla debes volver a rellenar la lista de cells, es decir, volver a buscarlos todos. Normalmente Selenim los devolverá siempre en el mismo orden, salvo que alguno desaparezca. Si la pagina que estas probando está disponible, indicalo y así podremos hacer un mejor ejemplo.

Comment: Hola @J barrio!! Gracias por responder... lamentablemente no puedo dar acceso a la página porque es administrativa y require un usuario y contraseña... si eso es lo que hago... los busco todoas las celdas otra vez... voy a actualizar la pregunta... voy a poner las partes del codigo que creo que muestran lo que estoy haciendo exactamnete....aunque no todo porque son mas de 700 lineas... a ver si logro acotar a lo mas relevante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He he logrado evitar la excepción (mas bien rodear el problema porque sigue estando ahí solo que he ido por un camino diferente al mismo sitio)...  no es como me hubiese gustado solucionarlo pero para lo que yo lo quiero me viene genial...

El problema lo causaba la ChildWindow que abro dentro de la página principal, esa childwindow abria una "SubPage"... pues lo que he hecho es simplemente no abrir esa childWindow, en su lugar he creado otra pestaña en el navegador y he abierto la página que se abria dentro de la chilwindow en esa nueva pestaña (muerto el perro se acabó la rabia). Ahora el programa me funciona perfecto.

Lo digo por si alguien tine un problema parecido que por lo menos sepa quien es el causante.

Y si alguien sabe como solucionar el problema en vez de rodearlo que lo comente por aquí que siempre es bueno aprender!! :-)
Saludos!!